# puppet doesn't remove old mount entry in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, puppet

I defined a simple class for mount a nfs share on host as follow(current)

```
class mounts {
    file { [ "/mnt/share", "/mnt/share/share1" ]:
    ensure => 'directory',
    }

    mount { '/mnt/share/share1':
    ensure  => 'mounted',
    device  => '192.168.122.1:/home/export',
    dump    => '0',
    fstype  => 'nfs',
    options => 'vers=3,defaults',
    pass    => '0',
    require => File[ "/mnt/share", "/mnt/share/share1" ],
    }
}
```

So now i have an entry in /etc/fstab on the puppet client

```
192.168.122.1:/home/export      /mnt/share/share1       nfs     vers=3,defaults 0       0
```

My problem is, the puppet class was defined in this way(OLD)

```
class mounts {
    file { '/mnt/nfs':
    ensure => 'directory',
    }

    mount { '/mnt/nfs':
    ensure  => 'mounted',
    device  => '192.168.122.1:/home/export',
    dump    => '0',
    fstype  => 'nfs',
    options => 'vers=3,defaults',
    pass    => '0',
    require => File[ "/mnt/nfs" ],
    }
}
```

And now i have two entries in the /etc/fstab

```
192.168.122.1:/home/export      /mnt/nfs        nfs     vers=3,defaults 0       0 #OLD
192.168.122.1:/home/export      /mnt/share/share1       nfs     vers=3,defaults 0       0 #NEW
```

why puppet doesn't remove the old entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puppet doesn't automatically remove something, just because it managed a setting in the past and the old resource no longer applies.

If you want to remove that old mount, then remove it with a with something like this.

```
mount { '/mnt/nfs':
  ensure  => absent,
}
```